# High "user rollbacks" in v$sysstat - what does it mean?

Tags: oracle

There are some people on my team running performance tests against an Oracle database.  During the execution of their scripts, they are seeing a large increase in the value of "user rollbacks" in the v$sysstat table.  During the hour long test simulating a couple hundred users, that value increases by hundreds of thousands.  The test executes, for the most part, read only operations to the database, or simple inserts.  So I would not expect any transactions to be rolling back.  What does this value mean?  Should I be concerned about this statistic?  What should I be looking at as to the cause?

If it matters, the tests are executing against an ASP.NET application that generates SQL through ADO.NET and ODP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suspect it is an artifact of how the application is 'ending' transactions that don't do updates.

Check the stat "rollback changes - undo records applied". That actually points to the amount of work done by rollbacks (ie how many changes actually had to be rolled back).

Comment: The "rollback changes - undo records applied" is also pretty high. I realize now that the system in question does make heavy use of insert into temporary tables that are emptied out at the end of a transaction.  It does this even for "read only" operations.  Could this be causing the heavy stats.